# Is there a single word for the emotion conveyed by the expression, "don't look at me"?

Tags: word-request

Is there a single word for the emotion conveyed by the expression, "I don't want to have anything to do with it"?

[image: niel de grazia tyson hands off]

Comment: I replaced your tag (which is used by only two other questions on this site) with the one that is commonly used for single-word requests. Please note, though, that it contains some requirements (which are very helpful for people who may want to answer this question).

Comment: What is the source of the image used here, please? Please provide proper attribution for any images that you embed.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. If the source is online, please include a link also. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457)

Comment: Also, the title and the body ask somewhat different questions. This is not ideal.

Comment: @DavidSiegel It is my firm belief that this person is always taking the piss, as the Brits say.